# Magmi root category not recognized

Tags: magento, import, magmi

I'm getting errors of this like when I use the magmi importer, following this doc http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer

> SKU FH-74739 - On the fly category creator/importer v0.2.5 - Cannot
>   find site root with names : Default Category

My csv file being read:

```
store,sku,categories
"Main Website Store",FH-74739,"[Default Category]::1::1::1/Clothing::0::1::1/TOPS::0::1::1"
"Main Website Store",FH-74393,"[Default Category]::1::1::1/Clothing::0::1::1/BOTTOMS::0::1::1"
"Main Website Store",FH-91916,"[Default Category]::1::1::1/Clothing::0::1::1/BOTTOMS::0::1::1"
```

In my magento, I have a root category called `Default Category`, capitalizations and all.

I'm not sure what the issue is. I tried it in the three different modes, where you skip, overwrite, or create new entries. All of them give the same error. Nothing at all is imported.

What is the correct syntax, or what am I missing when it comes to getting this to import successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `store` column needs to be the Magento **store code**.

Right now you are using `Main Website Store` when it should be more like `admin` or whatever your store code is set to.

Magmi is most likely throwing the error because it cannot find the store code associated with a category root named `Default Category`